# Pattern for running an application migration in php

Tags: php, design-patterns, migration, database-migration

I'm creating a migration system for an application. The migration is generally only related to the database, and it has 2 components: Schema migrations, and data migrations. I have the files structured like this:
[image]

What I'm doing is checking what version the user has installed, and then I start the migration process from that version to the latest one. The process is, I execute a sql script, and then I look up the corresponding php file to execute (if it exists). My question is, how can I structure the php file to avoid running into a duplicate functions, or duplicate functions. I would like to have standard naming for the php migrations; something like this:

```
Class Migrate {
    public function up() {
        // upgrade the data
    }

    public function down() {
        // downgrade the data
    }
}
```

The problem I run into is that each of those php files would have this class, and functions, and when I have all these being run from a loop, PHP complains about redeclaring classes.

How do I solve this? Is there a better way of doing this, or common approach to this?

Comment: why not just store a bunch of DIFFs? simply apply the required diffs in sequence so you patch8 8.0.0 -> 8.0.1 -> 8.0.2 -> 8.1.0, without ever having to EXECUTE any of that code?

Comment: How would I do that? Also, the functions of the php files involve database data manipulations as well as file operations (I don't think that can be done with diffs)